# Download CSV URL Code

Tags: c#

I am trying to download a CSV file from a URL, however, the response looks like this:

```
"\"\0T\0r\0a\0n\0s\0a\0c\0t\0i\0o\0n\0_\0I\0D\0\"\0,\0\"\0S\0t\0a\0t\0u\0s\0\"\
```

I can confirm that the URL works and I get a CSV file. Here is part of what it looks like:

"Transaction_ID","Status","Closed_By","Payment_Type","Date_Submitted","Date_Scheduled",

Is my code incorrect? How come I fail to receive a comma separated list?

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(reportLink);
HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());

// open the file "data.csv" which is a CSV file with headers
using (CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(sr, true))
{
    int fieldCount = csv.FieldCount;
    csv.MissingFieldAction = MissingFieldAction.ReplaceByEmpty;
    string[] headers = csv.GetFieldHeaders();
    while (csv.ReadNextRecord())
    {
    }
 }
```

Comment: Looks like UTF16, so you may need to specify a different encoding when creating your `StreamReader`

Comment: That worked!             HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(reportLink);
            HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

            // open the file "data.csv" which is a CSV file with headers
            using (CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.Unicode), true, ','))
            {

Comment: @RowlandShaw You may want to post that as an answer :)